# Old style numbers on cross-references and links

Tags: hyperref, typography, cleveref, oldstylenums

I am writing a document and want to have old style numbers whenever `hyperref` creates a links to something inside my document that is numbered. This includes references to numbered sections, pages (references inside text and also on table of contents, figures and table), theorems (`amsthm`), figures, tables etc. I use the `cleveref` package and the command `\cref` for references.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[hidelinks,linktocpage]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{Chapter}
\label{chapter}

\section{Section}
\label{section}

\section{Subsection}
\label{subsection}

\section{Subsubsection}
\label{subsubsection}

\begin{theorem}
\label{theorem}
A theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{figure}
    %\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
    \caption{An image.}
    \label{figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        0 & 1 \\
        2 & 3
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{A table.}
    \label{table}
\end{table}

References to \cref{chapter}, \cref{section}, \cref{subsection} and \cref{subsubsection}. References to \cref{theorem}, \cref{figure} and \cref{table}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `cfr-lm` package to switch to old style figures for the cross-references:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[linktocpage,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref-usedon}

\usepackage[rm={oldstyle=false}]{cfr-lm}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@cref}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\fontfamily{clm2j}\selectfont}{}{}
\makeatother


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\label{section}

\section{Subsection}
\label{subsection}

\section{Subsubsection}
\label{subsubsection}

\begin{definition}
\label{definition}
A definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
\label{theorem}
A theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{equation}
\label{equation}
0=1
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}
    %\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
    \caption{An image.}
    \label{figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        0 & 1 \\
        2 & 3
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{A table.}
    \label{table}
\end{table}

References to \cref{section,subsection} and \cref{subsubsection}. References to \cref{definition}, \cref{theorem}, \cref{equation}, \cref{figure} and \cref{table}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not generate old style figures on the table of contents, list of figures and list of tables.

Comment: @PedroG.Mattos The toc etc. is more like a table than a block of text. I would use lining figures there so the line spacing will look more even.

Comment: I understand. But I want the links to look different from non-links, and the links on my TOC are the numbers.