# Cleveref names in small caps

Tags: hyperref, typography, cleveref, small-caps

I want to have every name `cleveref` prints to be a link writing in small caps. Currently I do this manually for every name I can think of using `\crefname` and `\Crefname`, but this is not an elegant solution, and is a bad one because:

1. it is very time consuming to have to add the `\crefname` for every `\newtheorem` environment I want;
2. I may forget some name used by cleveref and only find out later when the document is finished.

I have read this post [Format cleveref labels including names](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569413/format-cleveref-labels-including-names), but the solution offered does not solve my needs beacuse I also want that, when I reference multiple objects (using `\cref`, `\crefrange` and the like), the text of the conjuntion "and" is NOT in small caps, only the links created by `hyperref`.

Is there a way to have a text in small caps whenever `hyperref` creates a link?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[oneside]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[hidelinks,linktocpage]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefname{figure}{\textsc{figure}}{\textsc{figures}}
\Crefname{figure}{\textsc{Figure}}{\textsc{Figures}}
\crefname{table}{\textsc{table}}{\textsc{tables}}
\Crefname{table}{\textsc{Table}}{\textsc{Tables}}
\crefname{theorem}{\textsc{theorem}}{\textsc{theorems}}
\Crefname{theorem}{\textsc{Theorem}}{\textsc{Theorems}}
\crefname{definition}{\textsc{definition}}{\textsc{definitions}}
\Crefname{definition}{\textsc{Definition}}{\textsc{Definitions}}
\crefname{equation}{\textsc{equation}}{\textsc{equations}}
\Crefname{equation}{\textsc{Equation}}{\textsc{Equations}}


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\label{section}

\section{Subsection}
\label{subsection}

\section{Subsubsection}
\label{subsubsection}

\begin{definition}
\label{definition}
A definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
\label{theorem}
A theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{equation}
\label{equation}
0=1
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}
    %\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
    \caption{An image.}
    \label{figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        0 & 1 \\
        2 & 3
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{A table.}
    \label{table}
\end{table}

References to \cref{section}, \cref{subsection} and \cref{subsubsection}. References to \cref{definition}, \cref{theorem}, \cref{equation}, \cref{figure} and \cref{table}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think `cleveref` has a (reasonably accessible) place where the font of the reference name can be controlled (I might be wrong though). `zref-clever`, however, has the `namefont` option.

Answer (score 0):

You could patch `\@cref`:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[linktocpage,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref-usedon}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@cref}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\scshape}{}{}

\AfterBeginDocument{
  \renewcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{ \textnormal{to}\nobreakspace}%
  \renewcommand{\crefpairconjunction}{ \textnormal{and}\nobreakspace}%
  \renewcommand{\creflastconjunction}{ \textnormal{and}\nobreakspace}%
  \renewcommand{\crefpairgroupconjunction}{ \textnormal{and}\nobreakspace}%
  \renewcommand{\creflastgroupconjunction}{, \textnormal{and}\nobreakspace}%
}
\makeatother


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\label{section}

\section{Subsection}
\label{subsection}

\section{Subsubsection}
\label{subsubsection}

\begin{definition}
\label{definition}
A definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
\label{theorem}
A theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{equation}
\label{equation}
0=1
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}
    %\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
    \caption{An image.}
    \label{figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        0 & 1 \\
        2 & 3
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{A table.}
    \label{table}
\end{table}

References to \cref{section,subsection} and \cref{subsubsection}. References to \cref{definition}, \cref{theorem}, \cref{equation}, \cref{figure} and \cref{table}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention, but this is not what I want because when I use multiple references in one `\cref` command, all the taxt becomes small caps, including the "and".

Answer (score 0):

If you use the PDF management (loaded by `\DocumentMetadata` there is a hook before links that can be set:

```
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass[oneside]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[hidelinks,linktocpage]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\ActivateGenericHook{hyp/link/cref}
\AddToHook{hyp/link/cref}{\scshape}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\cref@hyperlink#1#2#3\@nil{\hyper@link{cref}{#2}{#3}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\label{section}

\section{Subsection}
\label{subsection}

\section{Subsubsection}
\label{subsubsection}

\begin{definition}
\label{definition}
A definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
\label{theorem}
A theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{equation}
\label{equation}
0=1
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}
    %\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
    \caption{An image.}
    \label{figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        0 & 1 \\
        2 & 3
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{A table.}
    \label{table}
\end{table}

References to \cref{section}, \cref{subsection} and \cref{subsubsection}. References to \cref{definition}, \cref{theorem}, \cref{equation}, \cref{figure} and \cref{table}.

\crefrange{section}{subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this looks very good! I will try it and see if it works.

Comment: Is there a way to also turn all numbers used on hyperlinks to old style numbers?

Comment: This works perfectly, as far as I can tell. What does the command `\DocumentMetadata` do?

Comment: Also, I have tried changing ` \AddToHook{hyp/link/cref}{\scshape}` to ` \AddToHook{hyp/link/cref}{\scshape\fontfamily{clm2j}\selectfont}` (this requires the package `cfr-lm`) and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: I have asked about old style numbers on this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/713151/old-style-numbers-on-cross-references-and-links/713166?noredirect=1#comment1772543_713166